# Проверка на наличие символов в строке

Tags: java

Не до конца понимаю как мне реализовать функцию проверки логина на наличие в нём только цифр и латинских букв верхнего и нижнего регистра. То есть

```
    private boolean Checking_Login(String in_login)
{
    final char alf_number[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
            'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z','A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
            'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    boolean flag = false;
    for(int i=0; i<in_login.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<alf_number.length; j++)
        {
            if(in_login.charAt(i) == alf_number[j])
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
            if(!flag)
                return flag;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать регексом, думаю так будет логичнее и проще

```
String template = "([0-9A-Za-z])";
public boolean isMatchingRegexp(final String text, final String template)
{
    Pattern pattern = null;
    try
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(template);
    }
    catch(PatternSyntaxException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(pattern == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    final Matcher regexp = pattern.matcher(text);
    return regexp.matches();
}
```

Comment: String template = "([0-9A-Za-z]))"; скобка лишняя

Comment: извиняюсь, исправил